# integral, evaluate volume

Tags: integration

Consider the area in the first quadrant between the parabola $y=x^2$ , the line $y=0$ , and the line  $x=2$ .
If this area is rotated around the  y-axis, it generates a volume of revolution.  Evaluate the volume.

What I did:
$\int_{-2} ^{\ 2} \pi(\dfrac{x^2}{2})^2 dx $
I got $4\pi/3$

I wonder if I made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Yes, it's incorrect. Your integral represents the volume of the revolution obtained by taking the region bounded by $x = -2$, $x = 2$, and $y = \tfrac{1}{2}x^2$ and rotating about the $x$-axis.

If you want to use the **washer** method, then you should be integrating with respect to $y$ from $0$ to $4$. You'll need to identify an inner and outer radius as functions of $y$.

If you want to use the **shell** method, then you can integrate with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $2$. You'll need to identify a radius and a height as functions of $x$.

Comment: Thank you. Your hint is helpful. I wonder if I did it right using shell method:       2pi integral from 0 to 2 of x(x^2) dx
                    =2pi (1/4)(x^4) [0,2] 
                   = 8pi                             Thank you very  much.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.